# Device macro id for Tapjoy, Google Analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics, tapjoy

I wanted to create custom url for tracking ios installs in google analytics dashboard. I have been using Tapjoy to drive the installs.  While creating the custom url from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#url-builder it asks for a device id macro for custom ad networks.

Any idea what is the device id macro for tapjoy. Quick google search didnt get me any specific result.

Comment: @siddhanth: Are you able to find out something for your query. Please share if you have resolved this.

Comment: nope didn't find anything substantial in there, one can actually use Tapstream to analyze the installs.

Comment: Okay Siddhant. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For some reason when I go to your link and build a URL it doesn't ask me for the device id macro.

But maybe this can help: http://home.tapjoy.com/tech/product-overview/sdk-change-log/tapjoy-and-identifiers#ios

Comment: Welcome to SO! :) Please, when you add link to somewhere outside SO, you should at least briefly describe what solution is - that link can be 404 or whatever and we dont want to lost information about problem (i see you already got Informed badge, so you read [SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) ;)